# cast to the object for databounditem value

Tags: c#, linq

Hi if i bind result in datatable to a gridview, how do i get the databounditem back from that gridview? The below code failed as it cannot cast to the object.

```
  private void gvInv_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (null == gvInv.CurrentRow) return;
        inventory = (Inventory)gvInv.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
```

please advice.

Comment: What does the DataBoundItem. Claim to be in the debugger?

Comment: When i select the dataBoundItem, i would expect it returns me all the property in that object - inventory.

Comment: Yes, but when you look at `gvInv.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem` in the debugger, via a break-point in `gvInv_MouseUp`, **what is it**? That is the key to this...

Comment: it is the System.Data.DataRowView

Comment: @Marc Gravell: hi Marc, it is the System.Data.DataRowView

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, the `DataBoundItem` is a `DataRowView`, so I'm ***assuming*** that you have bound to a typed data-set, and `Invoice` is your specialized `DataRow`.

In that case, the object you want is the row-view's `.Row`, i.e.

```
var rowView = gvInv.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
if(rowView != null)
{
    inventory = rowView.Row as Inventory;
}
```

Comment: @Marc Gravell: i got this error on the line `rowView.Row as Inventory`   "Error 3 Cannot convert type 'System.Data.DataRow' to 'le.DataModel.Inventory' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion 
"

Comment: @belinq - well, **is** `Inventory` a typed DataRow, or is it completely unrelated?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Inventory is a class object. i wrote a class call Inventory.cs at DataModel call the Inventory

Comment: @belinq - right, so you've bound to a `DataTable` but you want to extract `Inventory` objects, which are ***completely*** unrelated, right? That is **not** a cast, that is a **convert**. Is that was you are trying to do?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Thanks for the reply, i think the Inventory object is related to the row i select. Let me clarify my situation, I first GetAll the Inventory from inventory table and bind to the gvInv using dataTable.   This is my code,   bsInv.DataSource = linqHelper.ToDataTable(inventory.Get() as List<Inventory>); gvInv.DataSource = bsInv; Then on MouseUp(), i would like to do  inventory = (Inventory)gvInv.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;

Comment: @belinq and what is linqHelper.ToDataTable?

Comment: That is to convert the Tolist() to become Datatable

Comment: I referred to this link for ToDataTable<T> [link](http://www.chinhdo.com/20090402/convert-list-to-datatable/)

Comment: @belinq my point being; when you do that you aren't binding to your original objects any more, unless you somehow track that association externally. But **why** are you doing this? DataGridView can bind *just fine* to an object model. Why not just: `DataSource = inventory.Get();` ???

Comment: @Marc Gravell: yes u got the point. The reason i did that is because i want to do the auto filter on my textbox which link to the gridview. meaning to say when i textchange on the textbox, it will auto reflect the gridview data. This features seem to be only working on the gridview which bind to a datatable. How i wish i don have to use the linqHelper.ToDataTable(..) also. :(